# Notation: Subsets of elements with same function values

Tags: notation

I have a finite set $A$ of real numbers. Then I have a function $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ that maps real numbers to integers.

I would like to split A into subsets such that for all elements in a subset, the function $F$ maps to the same integer. (We would have max. $|A|$ such subsets, if all $x \in A$ map to different integers, min. 1 such subsets if they map all to the same integer)

I would like to say something like "All subsets of A, such that for every subset the elements in that subsets map to the same integer regarding function $F$", but I have no idea how to write this down nicely. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We consider those sets $X \subseteq A$ such that $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}.\forall x \in X. F(x) = k$."

Comment: Great! That was obvious, I feel stupid now ;) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Partition $A$ into subsets $A_k$ with $F(x)=k$ for all $x\in A_k$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/850131)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: This answers the question in an optimal way, "sufficient reputation" or not.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term is *fiber*. You can say "Consider the fibers of $f$ in $A$".

A fiber of $f: X \to Y$ is just a set $f^{-1}(y) = \{ x \in X : f(x)=y \}$ for $y \in Y$.

It is always true that $X = \bigcup_{y \in Y} X_y$ where $X_y=f^{-1}(y)$. This is a partition of $X$ into disjoint parts.

In your case, by considering $f|A$, you get $A = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb Z} A_k$, where some (most) $A_k$ will be empty.